# Ampersands are not being replaced with commas in Python text file

Tags: python, csv, text

Because ampersands are a delimiter in the file I am trying to process, I am attempting to replace all the instances of ampersand with commas in a Python text file, however the below code has no effect on the file.

```
commafile = open('/ampersandfile.txt')
my_file_contents = commafile.read()
commafile.close()
commafile = open('/csvfile.csv', 'w')
commafile.write(my_file_contents.replace('&', '& ').replace(',  ', ', '))
commafile.close()
```

Comment: Don't you want to have `my_file_contents.replace('&', ',')` instead of `my_file_contents.replace('&', '& ').replace(',  ', ', ')` and to check the result in csvfile.csv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're replacing the ampersand with an ampersand plus a space.

Use this:

```
Python> "some & text".replace("&", ",")
```

See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace).

*Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.*

Answer (score 0):

Your `.replace()` parameters are wrong. Try this to replace "&" and also "& ".

```
commafile.write(my_file_contents.replace('&', ','))
```

Comment: @zondo That makes sense, I actually did not know that. Thank you.